# Best way to pause an iOS Audio Stream When Phone Call Comes In

Tags: ios, interrupt-handling

I use an `AVPlayerItem` to play a stream of music.  What is best way to pause the stream when a phone call comes in, and resume it when the call ends?

Answer (score -1):

I think, that you use `AVAudioPlayer`.

So `AVAudioPlayer` got methods - play/pause.

Sample code:

```
AVAudioPlayer *thePlayer;
[thePlayer pause];
```

Comment: I understand that, guess just not for sure what notification observers to set up for when a call begins and ends.